# RewriteCond even if partial path exists as physical path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I wanna understand why the RewriteCond statements don't work properly. I dont wanne run into the rule if i have already a file or a directory in the root exists. Please help.

ihave: **example.com/projectx/drupal/sites/etc**

iwanna: **projectx.example.com/drupal/sites/etc**

if the there **it is a folder projectx** i wanna do **nothing.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*?)/(.*) http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what do you get with these rules, which one does not seem to work?

Comment: the thing is that the `RewriteCond` for dir or file will match the whole path if it reflects an existing dir or file, not partial path

Comment: Thanks Nikos. if i have a folder already exists in root dir then i wanne got to:
example.com/existingfolder

if there is not a existig dir or file then please rewrite to folder.example.com/drupal/so on

Comment: thank you very much! Means that i have to add the {http_root}?

Comment: Do you want to avoid the rewrite if only the top folder exists for example but not the whole request path? Meaning **request: `example.com/projectx/drupal/sites/etc`** but **only top path exists: `example.com/projectx`** **not `example.com/projectx/drupal/sites/etc`**, what do you want to achieve in this case?

Comment: exactely! only if the top folder exists (projectx) for example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid rewrite rule even if only the top folder exists (but not necessarily the whole request path), then try sth like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # if WHOLE path not exists as dir
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # if WHOLE path not exists as file
    RewriteCond /$1 !-d # if TOP folder not exists as dir
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*?)/(.*) http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 # THEN rewrite rule
</IfModule>
```

reference: [Apache ModRewrite/RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

**Explanation:**

`RewriteCond /$1 !-d` checks the first matched group of its associated rewrite rule (`$1=([^/]*?)`) if it **does not exist as dir** which is what you want to avoid.

Comment: That's an great idea but we dont have access to $1 at the 3rd RewriteCond? Or not?

Comment: @Spiderjack, this is explained in the answer.`RewriteCond` **can access** matched groups from its associated `RewriteRule`